# Git checkout shortcut: Using numbers

Tags: git, shortcut

Is there any way to create a shortcut for `git checkout` such that you can `git checkout <number_of_branch_in_list_of_branches>`

For example, I would like to do the following sequence:

```
$ git branch
1. first_branch
2. second_branch
3. third_branch

$ git checkout 2 
You are now on branch "second_branch"
```

I have seen some shortcuts dealing with `git checkout @{-num}` but, from what I have seen, that is in reference to past branches. I don't care about my previous branch history but representing branch names by the order in which they are listed after doing `git branch`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+branch+numbers

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62137984/7976758